# Access object instantiated in main class from another class

Tags: java, oop, object, constructor, instantiation

I have class A, my main class. In this class, I make an instance of class B `classB B = new B(parameters);` and call it using `classB.method` to access methods and data inside class B. I also have class C which needs to use methods and data from class B, however I can't figure out how to access it via the object class A created since `classB` hasn't been created yet at compile time, and I can't re-instantiate it or I lose the data I loaded into it when I instantiate it in class A.

How do I get around this and access `classB` from my class C constructor?

Some code from class A:

```
final private static String[] imageLocations = {"wall.png", "floor.png", "char.png"}; //Stores initial image locations

public static void main(String[] args) {
        images = new LoadImages(imageLocations);
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                (new Thread(new BomberMan())).start();
            }
        });
    }
```

Some code from class B:

```
public class LoadImages {
     private Image[] imageArray;

     public LoadImages(String[] args){
         imageArray = new Image[args.length];
         for(int i = 0; i<args.length; i++){
             imageLoader(args[i], i);
         }
     }

     private boolean imageLoader(String imageAddress, int index){
         try{
             imageArray[index] = ImageIO.read(new File(imageAddress));
             return true;
         }catch(IOException ex){
             System.out.println("PICTURE LOADING ERROR");
             return false;
         }
     }

     public Image returnImage(int index){
         return imageArray[index];
     }

     public Image scaleImage(Image image, int width, int height){
         return(image.getScaledInstance(width, height, Image.SCALE_FAST));
     }
}
```

Code from class C (Nothing really yet)

```
public class Block {
    int blockID;
    int playerID;
    Image image; 

    public Block(int blockID){
        this.blockID = blockID;
        this.image = loadImages.returnImage(blockID); //Doesn't work
    }
}
```

Comment: You pass the instance of B to the constructor of C. Can you post some code?

Comment: I attempted to do that as an object but netbeans wouldn't let me call any methods. Ill post code now

Comment: -_- I was passing the instantiated class as an object instead of as an `ImageLoader`, working now thanks